# How to delete and recreate Postgres database, which has been create through docker-compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.7
    env_file:
      - ./postgres.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - './data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

Within that PG container I have database called 'orders' with user 'orderUser' and with password 'orderUserPassword'.
I need to completely remove that DB from Postgres container, than recreate it as it is a new database server with single blank database 'orders' within.

I've tried to change volume section bindings folders paths, but another containers are not working with changed paths.

Comment: Do you want to clean up locally or always on start, even when container is still there, remove the old one?

Comment: Yes, I would like to remove the old database-related data and recreate new empty database.

Comment: Maybe getting your environment and real situation and usage of the containers will help. Why do you want t DB to be reset?

Comment: lol it's a local dev environment, totally reasonable to not give s$%t about wanting to migrate fixture data and cat images to a major version bump of a db engine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I've reached desired result, but it is not so clear (maybe).

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.7
    env_file:
      - ./postgres.env
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      # - './data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
      - './data/postgres3:/opt/pgsql/data/data2'
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
```

I've changed the `volume` section in my docker-compose file. Created new directory `postgres3` - it will persist container data. And added the following param in my local `postgres.env` file:
`PGDATA=/opt/pgsql/data/data2`
As I can see those actions allowed me to create another volume next to old one and use this new volume as new storage for new empty database.